# CouchDB - Proper way to use the Document Revision Number?

Tags: couchdb

We are new to Couch DB and are uncertain about how to use the document revision number. In particular, we are not sure if the client application should be aware of this revision number, and if it should have to send it back to the server with each save request to ensure continuity.

Our situation is that we have a NodeJS server in between CouchDB and a client application ( a game written in Actionscript 3 ). The game world is broken into a grid, and there can potentially be several changes to a single tile within a short time, each producing a new save request. As there is no assurance that two simultaneous requests will arrive at the server in a particular order, we need to make sure that the tile data will only be saved if it is newer than the data that is already in the database.

We are considering using a custom transaction ID that we attach to each document, but we are concerned that we may just be doing it wrong, or are missing some fundamental behaviour of CouchDB ( ie, the "Right Way" )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, include the `_rev` property with every save.  From http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#PUT

> To update an existing document, you also issue a PUT request. In this case, the JSON body must contain a _rev property, which lets CouchDB know which revision the edits are based on. If the revision of the document currently stored in the database doesn't match, then a 409 conflict error is returned.

For information about conflict management, see: http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/conflicts.html#working